# GitLab CI manual start of pipeline with only include

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline with only include like this

```
---
include:
  - project: "test/devops/gitlabci-templates"
    ref: "2.0"
    file: "templates/terraform/all.yml"
```

is there a way to add rules or trigger it manually instead of starting it on every push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include:`s [support use of `rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include). You can do this directly on the template include, or you can do it for the jobs specified in the template.

```yaml
include:
  - project: "test/devops/gitlabci-templates"
    ref: "2.0"
    file: "templates/terraform/all.yml"
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```